# two ActiveRecord Model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I have two active record model now, `User` and `Event`
There are many events, user can choose to  interested in an event or decide to participant the event.

How to write the migration and model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shweta suggested, you need a many to many relationship. In fact it looks like you need two, one for interests, and one for participations. The simplest implementation relies on has_and_belongs_to_many:

User model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :interests, :class_name => Event, :join_table => "interests_users"
has_and_belongs_to_many :participations, :class_name => Event, :join_table => "participations_users"
```

Event model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, :class_name => User, :join_table => "interests_users"
has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, :class_name => User, :join_table => "participations_users"
```

In your join table migration:

```
def change
  create_table :interests_users, :id => false do |t| 
    t.integer :event_id
    t.integer :user_id
  end 

  create_table :participations_users, :id => false do |t| 
    t.integer :event_id
    t.integer :user_id
  end 
end
```

You should be able to continue from here

Answer (score 0):

But who creates the events? 
I think this assosiation will be good for you:

```
models/event.rb 
   has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
models/user.rb
   belongs_to :event
```

And user migration should looks like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :event_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :event_id
  end
end
```

Event migration:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You can read more information about rails assosiations in this guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: how should I distinguish **intertesed in** and **participant** ?

Answer (score 0):

**User model**

```
 has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Event model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Event migration:**

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string      :name
      t.references  :user
      t.boolean :participant, :default => true, :null => false # the user is participant by default set, default to true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I should mention that user can have no relationship with an event, not interested or participant

Comment: is it like, user can participate or interested in many events? then you need a many to many relation between user and event